# Calculate monthly days person active

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

I have data in my table this way

| Start_Dt | End_Dt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1Jan2021 | 24Apr2021 | Active |
| 25Apr2021 | 10Jun2021 | Inactive |
| 11Jun2021 | 15Jan2022 | Active |

I want to calculate Active days monthly. In this case Active monthly days will be

Total Active Days = (31/31 + 28/28 + 31/31 + 24/30 + 20/30 + 31/31 + 31/31 + 30/30 + 31/31 + 30/30 + 31/31) / 12 = 0.8722

How do I derive the active days for each month in 1 year?

Answer (score 0):

Use a row generator to generate all the months and join to your table and aggregate:

```sql
WITH months (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2021-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT SUM(
         ( LEAST(ADD_MONTHS(m.month, 1), end_dt + 1)
           - GREATEST(m.month, start_dt) )
         / (ADD_MONTHS(m.month, 1) - m.month)
       ) / 12 AS avg_active_days_per_month_2021
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN months m
       ON (   t.start_dt < ADD_MONTHS(m.month, 1)
          AND t.end_dt   > m.month )
WHERE  t.status = 'Active'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Start_Dt, End_Dt, Status) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-04-24', 'Active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-25', DATE '2021-06-10', 'Inactive' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-06-11', DATE '2022-01-15', 'Active' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | AVG_ACTIVE_DAYS_PER_MONTH_2021 |
> | --- |
> | .8722222222222222222222222222222222222225 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=42b0378383486be7d4cb08c1ed553022)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get monthly active days even when there is more then one period of inactivity.
In the WITH clause there are just the sample data in a table with two periods of inactivity (to make it more complicated).
The cte **inact** separates inactivity periods, and cte **months** generates months with starting dates and number of days per month.
In the main Select, all the job is done using CASE in the subquery calculating active days out of dates of inactivities and number of days per month.
Hope this could be of help to you. Regards...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-03-24' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-03-25' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-04-10' "END_DATE", 'Inactive' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-04-11' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-07-18' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-07-19' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-07-30' "END_DATE", 'Inactive' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-07-31' "START_DATE", DATE '2022-01-25' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL
        ),
--  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    inact AS
        (
            SELECT 
                 Count(START_DATE) OVER(ORDER BY START_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "NUM_OF_INACTIVITIES",
                 START_DATE  "INACT_START", 
                 END_DATE "INACT_END"
            FROM 
                tbl
            WHERE 
                To_Char(START_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2021' And
                STATUS = 'Inactive'
        ),
    months AS
        (
            SELECT
                LPAD(To_Char(LEVEL), 2, '0') "WRK_MONTH",
                To_Date('2021-' || LPAD(To_Char(LEVEL), 2, '0') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "MONTH_START",
                To_Number(To_Char(LAST_DAY(To_Date('2021-' || LPAD(To_Char(LEVEL), 2, '0') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')), 'dd')) "MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS",
                i.INACT_START,
                i.INACT_END
            FROM
                DUAL d
            INNER JOIN
                inact i ON(1=1)
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
        )
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  
    x.MONTH, 
    Min(ACTIVE_DAYS) "ACTIVE_DAYS"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.WRK_MONTH "MONTH",
            m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS "MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS",
            CASE 
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH < To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'mm') THEN To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS) || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS) 
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH = To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'mm') And m.WRK_MONTH < To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'mm') THEN To_Char(m.INACT_START - 1, 'dd') || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS)
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH > To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'mm') And m.WRK_MONTH < To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'mm') THEN  '0' || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS)
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH > To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'mm') And m.WRK_MONTH = To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'mm') THEN  To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS - To_Number(To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'dd'))) || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS)
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH = To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'mm') And m.WRK_MONTH = To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'mm') THEN To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS - (To_Number(To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'dd')) - To_Number(To_Char(m.INACT_START, 'dd')))) || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS)
                WHEN m.WRK_MONTH > To_Char(m.INACT_END, 'mm') THEN To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS) || '/' || To_Char(m.MONTH_NUM_OF_DAYS)
            ELSE Null
            END "ACTIVE_DAYS"
        FROM
            months m
    ) x
INNER JOIN
    inact i ON(1 = 1)
GROUP BY 
    x.MONTH
ORDER BY 
    x.MONTH
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  MONTH ACTIVE_DAYS                                                                     
--  ----- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  01    31/31                                                                             
--  02    28/28                                                                             
--  03    24/31                                                                             
--  04    20/30                                                                             
--  05    31/31                                                                             
--  06    30/30                                                                             
--  07    20/31                                                                             
--  08    31/31                                                                             
--  09    30/30                                                                             
--  10    31/31                                                                             
--  11    30/30                                                                             
--  12    31/31
```

And with three periods of inactivity...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-03-24' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-03-25' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-04-10' "END_DATE", 'Inactive' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-04-11' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-07-18' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-07-19' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-07-30' "END_DATE", 'Inactive' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-07-31' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-08-25' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-08-26' "START_DATE", DATE '2021-11-03' "END_DATE", 'Inactive' "STATUS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT DATE '2021-11-04' "START_DATE", DATE '2022-08-25' "END_DATE", 'Active' "STATUS" FROM DUAL
        )
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  MONTH ACTIVE_DAYS                                                                     
--  ----- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  01    31/31                                                                             
--  02    28/28                                                                             
--  03    24/31                                                                             
--  04    20/30                                                                             
--  05    31/31                                                                             
--  06    30/30                                                                             
--  07    20/31                                                                             
--  08    25/31                                                                             
--  09    0/30                                                                              
--  10    0/31                                                                              
--  11    27/30                                                                             
--  12    31/31
```